# How to deploy model, when model has dummy columns?

Tags: python, flask

I have categorical column so, I convert them as dummy columns and use minmax scaling for rest of integer columns. And I fit this converted data into model. Now when deploying the model (**Flask**) how deploy.

After get variable input from HTML how to convert them as dummy variables as like model?

Please provide any samples if possible for deployment file with dummy columns.

This is my deployment code for model which has dummy columns (*app.py*)

```
    int_features = [x for x in request.form.values()]
    #int_features = pd.DataFrame([np.array(int_features)], columns=['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt','education', 'education_num', 'marital_status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'capital_gain', 'capital_loss', 'hpw', 'country'])
    df = pd.read_csv('adult.csv').drop('salary', axis = 'columns')
    df.append(int_features, ignore_index = True)
    df_new = pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True)
    def norm_func(i):
        x = (i-i.min()) /(i.max()-i.min())
        return(x)

    df_new = norm_func(df_new)
    
    final = pd.DataFrame(df_new.iloc[-1:,])
    inputs = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[-1:,])
    prediction = int(model.predict(final))
    return render_template('final1.html', data = inputs, prediction_text='Result: {}'.format(prediction))
```

I append with input data with main data in order to use the dummy variables conversion and minmax scaler (which is *norm_func*). After conversion spilt end row of data from full data (which is input from user), predict for the row and display the result.

Am correctly doing this or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Summary: Process your int_features and categorical features(adult.csv) separately. After that, concatenate the both df into same row. Pass this single row to your model for prediction.

Detailed:

**int_features**

[image: int_features]

**df**

[image: df]

`df_new = pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=False)`

[image: df_new]

`int_features = norm_func(int_features)`

[image: norm_func(int_features)]

`df_new = pd.concat([df_new, int_features], axis=1)`

[[image: concat df_new, int_features5]

(You can normalize after concatenation, based on your model)

Now, pass each row to your model for prediction.